# При изменении сессии на fastify, она не изменяется глобально

Tags: typescript, fastify

Я хочу создать сессию аутентификации в fastify и установить для него значение false, затем после выполнения некоторого первого метода некоторого класса сеанс изменяется на true, но проблема в том, что сеанс изменяется только в первом методе и изменения не видны в других методах, кроме первого, когда я вывожу в консоль в первом методе свою сессию, я вижу измененную версию, т. е. значение равно true. Далее появляется второй метод,в котором, по моей задумке, должно выводить в консоль уже измененную сессию аутентификации на true, но возникает проблема, что сеанс не изменился и выводит в консоль самое первое заданное мной значение, т.е false вместо true, методы написаны на TypeScript.

Вот пример кода

это index.ts

```
const fastifySession = require('@fastify/session');
const fastifyCookie = require('@fastify/cookie');


dotenv.config();

const server = require("fastify")();
server.register(fastifyCookie, {secure: false});
server.register(fastifySession, {secret: 'a secret with minimum length of 32 characters'});

server.addHook('preHandler', (req:any, reply:any, next:any) => {
        req.session.auth = false;
        next()
});
```

это первый метод

```
async login(req: any, reply: any) {
        req.session.set('auth', true)
        req.session.save()
        console.log(req.session.auth)
        return req.session.auth
    }
```

это второй метод

```
 async getAuth(req: any, reply: any) {
       
        console.log(req.session.auth)
        reply.send(JSON.stringify(req.session.auth))
    }
```